# Get rid of spaces between spans

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to emulate a tab bar with HTML.

I'd like the width of each tab to be set according to the text length (that is, no fixed width) and to word wrap in case it exceeds the screen width.

I've almost achieved it:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    #myTabs .tab {
    float: left;
    }

    #myTabs .tab_middle {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
    background-image:url('images/tabs/tab_middle.png');
    }

    #myTabs .tab_left {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        background-image:url('images/tabs/tab_left.png');
    }

    #myTabs .tab_right {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
    background-image:url('images/tabs/tab_right.png');
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="myTabs">
  <div class='tab'>
        <span class='tab_left'>&nbsp;</span>
        <span class='tab_middle'>very very looong</span>
        <span class='tab_right'>&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
  <div class='tab'>
        <span class='tab_left'>&nbsp;</span>
        <span class='tab_middle'>another loooong tab</span>
        <span class='tab_right'>&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But, there's a very annoying space between the opening tab image and the closing one.

As you can see, I've tried with padding, spacing, and border, with no luck.

**EDIT:**
I tried replacing the spans with a small table (one row, three `<td>`s), but it's the same, only the space between is smaller.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Get rid of the newlines between the spans. Example:

```html
<div class='tab'>
  <span class='tab_left'>&nbsp;</span><span class='tab_middle'>very very looong</span><span class='tab_right'>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Newlines are counted as a space in HTML.

Answer (score 64):

Another way besides **njbair**'s one is to add `font-size: 0` to parent element.
I prefer this one because it's aesthetically better for tab designing.

Instead of this:

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <span id="mytab1">Tab 1</span><span id="mytab2">Tab 2</span><span id="mytab3">Tab 3</span>
</div>
```

...we can use this:

```html
<div id="tabs" style="font-size: 0;">
    <span id="mytab1">Tab 1</span>
    <span id="mytab2">Tab 2</span>
    <span id="mytab3">Tab 3</span>
</div>
```

...which looks better :)

Of course, don't forget to define your real font size for tabs.

**EDIT**:
There's one more way to get rid of spaces: by adding comments.

Example:

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <span id="mytab1">Tab 1</span><!--
    --><span id="mytab2">Tab 2</span><!--
    --><span id="mytab3">Tab 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it does what the OP is requesting. The OP wanted the spaces between spans not to be seen, and the accepted answer is just removing it from the html.

Comment: @HectorOrdonez People has been asking on meta if there should be a community accepted answer, but it was rejected, mainly because it is which answer suits OP's the most and not the community, a community answer is the most upvoted one however. So don't bother about which one should be the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Nice tip on the comments. Hard to pick which is the lesser of two evils: CSS hack requiring duplicating font size info or HTML hack which feels like changing the content to achieve the desired style.

Comment: Just chiming in as the author of the accepted answer. You'll notice that the OP was using 3 spans per tab: one acting as the left edge, one as the middle part, and one as the right edge. In that context he can still put each tab on a new line, just not in between the spans that make up the same tab.

Comment: What happens when you add comments?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use nagative `letter-spacing:-10px` - that has a lighter impact on formatting.

```
<div id="tabs" style="letter-spacing:-10px;">
    <span id="mytab1" style="letter-spacing:1px;">Tab 1</span>
    <span id="mytab2" style="letter-spacing:1px;">Tab 2</span>
    <span id="mytab3" style="letter-spacing:1px;">Tab 3</span>
</div>
```

Got this idea thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46048130/873481)

Answer (score 0):

hard to test without the images but I added background color and display:inline to the root tabs. Please try this:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    #myTabs .tab {
        float: left;
        display:inline;
    }

    #myTabs .tab_middle {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
    background-image:url('images/tabs/tab_middle.png');
    }

    #myTabs .tab_left {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        background-image:url('images/tabs/tab_left.png');
    }

    #myTabs .tab_right {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
    background-image:url('images/tabs/tab_right.png');
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="myTabs">
  <div class='tab' style="background-color:Red;">
        <span class='tab_left'>&nbsp;</span>
        <span class='tab_middle'>very very looong</span>
        <span class='tab_right'>&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
  <div class='tab' style="background-color:Green;">
        <span class='tab_left'>&nbsp;</span>
        <span class='tab_middle'>another loooong tab</span>
        <span class='tab_right'>&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice try, but the space is still there, in red on the first tab and green on the second...

Answer (score 0):

Tab middle, left and right also need to float left.

Answer (score 0):

njbair’s response is correct.

Another option was to use a table, with the `border-collapse: collapse;` property.

Another gotcha: in Internet Explorer 6.0, the first approach (spans) doesn’t work as expected. When resizing the window, IE wordwraps the span, breaking the tab, while with the table approach even IE sends down the whole tab.