# CSS: Nested span tags behave differently when you type differently?

Tags: css

Those 2 blocks of code are the same but when they are output, they look differently. There is a gutter in between each characters on the second one?

```
<span>A<span>B<span>C</span></span></span>

<span>A
  <span>B
    <span>C</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/ptJwI

Comment: Why would you ever write span like this? How could a browser even really know what is happening?

Comment: It is not for actual production. I am just wondering why 2 seemingly same code give me different output.

Comment: In that case, Ishank has answered the question. I do just want to point out that those span tags wouldn't know who was completing who - http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/c7aHt/    - But interesting point.

Comment: For those curious, an experimental usage of nested spans. Purely just for fun. http://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/FEBvb

Comment: That is pretty great. I have used lettering.js for this in the past. It puts the spans in with javascript so you don't have to deal with the markup. You should check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because *enter* or '\n' is equal to a space in HTML

Comment: Note that this is only with an inline element, as you seem to say it is always this way.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the the inline-block 4px padding that built in your browser. the option to decline this space is to use like you do with out space between the > to < of spans

the other option is to use negative margin left in 4px to each of the element except the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that using comments to get rid of the space looks more elegant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519923/css-get-rid-of-spaces-between-spans

Comment: Thanks for comment. is also option to use comments but remember the file can edited by another IDE's and people and the HTML not look good with HTML combination this is why i'm say is better to use CSS to control it.