# how browser renders 'span'?

Tags: html, css

```
  <p>
    <span>cancel</span><span>comfirm</span>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <p>
    <span>cancel</span>
    <span>confirm</span>
  </p>
```

hey should show me the same result. but in the second template, after rendering, there is 'space' between 'cancel' and 'confirm'.

tags are inline elements so the line break will no use.

i can float them both with CSS.

but, i don't know the reason. i just think block tags will have space.

[ref img](http://7xsubf.com2.z0.glb.clouddn.com/2016-04-11%2011.20.33.png)

Comment: No, they should not show you the same result. Note you do have spaces in the source between the first two spans.

Comment: Why don't you just put then behind each other: <span>cancel</span><span>confirm</span>

Comment: Adding a PLUNKR for ease --> https://plnkr.co/edit/MNbG7KH7cEFvmOGkKflL?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2519948/4759033

Comment: @Cristy well, it's not a duplicate. OP is asking why it happens, he is not asking how to fix it.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It is explained in the answers to that question why it is happening: `Newlines are counted as a space in HTML.` and there are also given several solutions to his problem.

Comment: You don't know the reason because your understanding is completely wrong. If nothing else, you have the whole thing backwards - whitespace is insignificant only between block elements, not inline elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: OP edited his question after it was answer, still, answer is
>   applicable, he just changed the order of DOM hence now his image is
>   correct.

I think your image is incorrect. It should be showing white space in the [first `p` element](https://jsfiddle.net/ex7pxfxr/1/) and not the second one. As `span` is an `inline` element, it will result in whitespace being rendered by browsers when you have a line break between inline elements in your source.

You can hack that in several ways by putting those elements in a single line in your source code which you are already doing in your 2<sup>nd</sup> example, or you can use `font-size: 0;` on your parent element and re-set `font-size` for child elements, or you can put an empty comment like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ex7pxfxr/).

Comment: Please note that `font-size:0` may not be the right solution everywhere, as there are browsers that do not treat this correctly. Opera 12 for instance used the minimal font size (as set in the user preferences, for instance 8px) whenever you have `font-size:0`.

Comment: @dukegod Still, answer remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Span is for a group of text that you'd like to apply a similar style to. Span by default has no style applied to it. Span is generally used for styling to specific part of data. Span is not rendered as anything or something on browser.